# where i should define task id for SwiftFlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.taskIdentifier = "your.custom.task.identifier"

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I wanted to make a listener for sending notifications in ios and Android
It is working in Android but in ios not working When I close the application I add this code in info.plist file:

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
   <string>com.ebtekar.supporttest</string>
</array>
```

but I don't know where should I add the function id (task id) in flutter code with flutter_background_service